# how to color portion of a text in spark richtext flex

Tags: apache-flex, richtext, flex-spark

I am trying to color part of a text in spark richtext. Below is what I've tried, but it doesn't show up as I thought it would be. I am getting all black color.

```
private var helpText:String = "<p><span style=\"color:#FF0000;\">
    The quick</span> brown fox jumps over the lazy dogg.</p>";

<s:RichText id="help" width="100%" textFlow="{TextFlowUtil.importFromString(helpText)}"
            textAlign="center" fontFamily="enFont">
```

I have checked this also

```
<s:RichText id="help" width="100%" textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(helpText, 
                                             TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}"
            textAlign="center" fontFamily="enFont">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `helpText` to use the following markup:

```
private var helpText:String = "<p><span color=\"#FF0000;\">The quick</span> brown fox jumps over the lazy dogg.</p>";
```

HTML text in Flex works a bit differently for inline CSS; just use the style name directly when you set style attributes (see the [styles section](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/RichText.html) in the RichText docs for more details).